# Carbon - today or future date only

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I am having problem with validating the `$pickUpDate` date. When I select today date and submit - I get an error: `Pick-up: today or future date only`

It should allow me to use today or future date only. It should NOT allow less than today date.

```
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        $pickUpDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('D j M Y', $this->pickup_date);
        $dropOffDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('D j M Y', $this->dropoff_date);

        $todayDate = Carbon::now();

        if (!$pickUpDate->gte($todayDate)) {
            $validator->errors()->add('pickup_date', 'Pick-up: today or future date only');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just before your if statement, dump the $pickUpDate and $todayDate values. I have a feeling that the hours, minutes and second in the pickUpDate is showing at midnight where Carbon::now() is showing the current time. You may need to swap to Carbon::today() instead of Carbon::now().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `today()` will return start time of today you will need to add `->endOfDay()` in the end.

```
Carbon::now()->endOfDay();
```

or add minutes:

```
Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5);
```

In your case, you are adding `now()` in the function wich checks if this time is past. As this function takes time to check (maybe milliseconds) it will return false. add 1 minute to your now carbon object and it will be fine.